# How to read binary video format in HDFS using pyspark?

Tags: bigdata, pyspark

We want to work on detection of pedestrians in a video using ML algorithm.But the video is in the HDFS file system.How can we read the binary video file format from HDFS using spark?

Please help me on this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Have you gone through this already.? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414189/how-can-i-read-in-a-binary-file-from-hdfs-into-a-spark-dataframe?rq=1

Comment: yes.But i am not getting the clear idea.

Comment: @IamTheRealFord I am particularly asking for binary video file.